# where is the default location for the odbc ini config file for unixodbc on macosx?

Tags: macos, odbc, homebrew

I used:

`brew install unixodbc` to install unixodbc on my macbook (10.14)

but I cannot find the location for the odbc ini config file?
any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The location pointed by the [`unixodbc` formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/8a9b647fda279255998ef6aa3634cf8ee49a4978/Formula/unixodbc.rb) is Homebrew’s `etc` directory:

```
$(brew --prefix)/etc
```

If you’ve installed Homebrew in its default location, `/usr/local`, the `odbc.ini` file should be located here:

```
/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
```